# What is the shape of the Sun's orbit around the Milky Way?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, sun, milky-way

Here is a question for you really bright folks. How does the motion of the sun along the midpoint of the plane of the galaxy look like? I suspect it to travel above and then below the plane but I would think its path would be in the shape of a screw.

Comment: According [Ice Age Epochs and the Sun's Path through the Galaxy][1], the Sun's path through the galaxy extends 70 parsecs above and below the galactic plane and varies between 7.9 and 8.6 kiloparsecs from the galactic center.  One orbit of the galaxy takes about 230 million years.


  [1]: http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/626/2/844/fulltext/

Comment: The Sun travels through the spiral arms of the Milky Way disk, rather than simply traveling with the pattern of arms.